# Pythonic way to compute sensitivity and specificity

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute the sensitivity and specificity of 2 numpy arrays (test, truth). Both arrays have the same shapes and store only the numbers 0 (test/truth false), 1 (test/truth true). Therefore I had to compute the false_positives, true_positives, false_negative and true_negative values. I did it this way:

```py
true_positive = 0
false_positive = 0
false_negative = 0
true_negative = 0

for y in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for x in range(mask.shape[1]):
        if (mask[y,x] == 255 and truth[y,x] == 255):
            true_positive = true_positive + 1
        elif (mask[y,x] == 255 and truth[y,x] == 0):
            false_positive = false_positive + 1
        elif (mask[y,x] == 0 and truth[y,x] == 255):
            false_negative = false_negative + 1
        elif (mask[y,x] == 0 and truth[y,x] == 0):
            true_negative = true_negative + 1

sensitivity = true_positive / (true_positive + false_negative)
specificity = true_negative / (false_positive + true_negative)
```

I think there could exist a much easier (more readable) way because it's python and not C++ ... First I tried something like: `true_positive = np.sum(mask == 255 and truth == 255)` but I got this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Is there a more pythonic way to compute the sensitivity and specificity?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in checking scikit-learn sklearn.metrics it has a tonne of metrics to choose from  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focusing on compactness through NumPy supported [`ufunc-vectorized`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) operations, [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`array-slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), here's an approach -

```
C = (((mask==255)*2 + (truth==255)).reshape(-1,1) == range(4)).sum(0)
sensitivity, specificity = C[3]/C[1::2].sum(), C[0]/C[::2].sum()
```

Alternatively, going a bit *NumPythonic*, we could have counts `C` with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
C = np.bincount(((mask==255)*2 + (truth==255)).ravel())
```

To make sure we are getting floating pt numbers as the ratios, at the start, we need to use : `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: I finished my answer for completeness sake, but this is truly the better answer...

Comment: Great! Thank you! Looks so much better :)

Answer (score 2):

test for same shape:

```
a = np.random.rand(4,4)
b = np.random.rand(4,4)
print(a.shape == b.shape) #prints true
```

test for truth values:

```
#assuming you have scaled a and b to only include 1 or 0 (divide by 255)
true_positive = np.sum(mask * truth)

true_negative = len(mask.flat) - np.count_nonzero(mask + truth)

false_positive = np.count_nonzero(mask - truth == 1)

false_negative = np.count_nonzero(truth - mask == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The four arrays can be find and organized like that:

```
categories=dstack((mask&truth>0,mask>truth,mask<truth,mask|truth==0))
```

then the scores :

```
tp,fp,fn,tn = categories.sum((0,1))
```

finally the results :

```
sensitivity,specificity = tp/(tp+fn),tn/(tf+fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is use `collections.Counter` from standard library.

```
# building pair list (can be shortened to one-liner list comprehension, if you want)
pair_list = []
for y in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for x in range(mask.shape[1]):
        pair_list.append((mask[y, x], truth[y, x]))

# getting Counter object
counter = collections.Counter(pair_list)
true_positive = counter.get((255, 255))
false_positive = counter.get((255, 0))
false_negative = counter.get((0, 255))
true_negative = counter.get((0, 0))
```

Comment: this is relatively nice looking, but will likely be an order of magnitude or more slower than using `numpy`